Free groups have Haagerup's property H
I've been reading about Haagerup's property H for groups and the fact that all free groups have this property. I thought it would be a fun exercise to try and prove this myself, but I'm a little stuck.
The definition I'm using is that a discrete group $G$ has property H if it admits a sequence $(\varphi_n)_n$ of positive definite functions which vanish at infinity and converge pointwise to $1$.
My attempt for the free groups was to define $\varphi_n(g)=\frac{n}{n+l(g)},$ where $l(g)$ is the the length of $g.$ It's clear these vanish at infinity and converge pointwise to $1$ but as expected the hard part is checking positive definiteness.
I suspect this might be true for the following reason: for all $g_1,g_2,...,g_n \in G$ the matrix $\left[\frac{n}{n+l(g_i)+l(g_j)} \right]_{i,j}$ is (semi-)positive definite and my feeling is that in the "generic case" you wouldn't expect too much cancellation in $g_i^{-1}g_j$ so that for $i\neq j$ at least $l(g_i^{-1}g_j)$ shouldn't be too far off from $l(g_i)+l(g_j)$. It's not entirely clear to me if this can be made into a proof though.
Would anyone happen to know if indeed the above $\varphi_n$'s are positive definite? Or if not could anyone maybe provide a hint for a correct proof?
